# Solve a symbolic expression

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I'm working with the Hoek Brown plastic yield surface to model soil/rock materials.

The yield surface is given by:

[image]

Were sig1 and sig3 are the maximum and minimum [principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_surface) stresses. sigc, m, s and n are constants.

In order to parametrize this yield surface to principal stress space  (PSS), it's written in function of cylindrical coordinates xi, rho and beta:

```
sig[xi_, rho_, beta_] := {xi/Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[2/3] rho Cos[beta], 
  xi/Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[2/3] rho Cos[beta - 2 Pi/3], 
  xi/Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[2/3] rho Cos[beta + 2 Pi/3]}
```

The Hoek Brown yield functions in PSS is given by:

```
HoekBraunYield[xi_, rho_, beta_] := 
 sig[xi, rho, beta][[1]] - sig[xi, rho, beta][[3]] - 
  sigc (-m sig[xi, rho, beta][[1]]/sigc + s)^n

HoekBraunYield[xi, rho, beta]
```

But this is a scalar function. I need a vector HB(xi,rho,beta) in PSS with HB(xi,rho,beta)={0,0,0}.

So I isolate xi:

```
fhbeq = HoekBraunYield[xi, rho, beta] /. {Cos[beta] -> cosb, 
   Sin[beta + Pi/6] -> sibbpi6}
solxi = Solve[fhbeq == 0, xi][[1, 1]]
```

And put it back in HB equation again:

```
fhbeq2 = fhbeq /. solxi /. {cosb -> Cos[beta], 
    sibbpi6 -> Sin[beta + Pi/6]} // Simplify
```

To get HB in function only of rho and beta:

```
Sqrt[3/2] rho Cos[beta] + (rho Sin[beta])/Sqrt[2] - 
 sigc (6^(-(1/2)/n) ((rho (3 Cos[beta] + Sqrt[3] Sin[beta]))/sigc)^(1/
    n))^n
```

Now I need to isolate rho in the equation below, but Mathematica keep running and I get no results. Is there a way to do that?

```
eq = (rho (Sqrt[3] cos + sin))/Sqrt[2] - 
   sigc (6^(-(1/2)/n) ((rho (3 cos + Sqrt[3] sin))/sigc)^(1/n))^n;
Solve[eq == 0, rho]
```

[reference](https://ascelibrary.org/doi/full/10.1061/%28ASCE%29EM.1943-7889.0001737)

Comment: For any non-zero integer value of $n$, `eq==0`.  Is $n$ restricted to being a non-zero integer?  If so then any real value of `rho` satisfies `eq==0`.

Comment: @ JimB n is a real value >0.

Comment: Ooops!  I didn't check other values of $n$ (as I'm just used to assuming a variable named $n$ is an integer).  It appears that `eq==0` for all non-zero real values of $n$.  Maybe something is wrong in the equations presented?

Comment: @JimB: In 13 on Windows 10 `eq = (rho (Sqrt[3] cos + sin))/Sqrt[2] - 
   sigc (6^(-(1/2)/n) ((rho (3 cos + Sqrt[3] sin))/sigc)^(1/n))^n;
Solve[eq == 0, rho, Assumptions -> n > 0]` produces `{{}}` i.e. no solution.

Comment: @user64494 I agree.  However, plugging in any non-zero number for $n$ results in `eq==0`.

Comment: @JimB: `eq = (rho (Sqrt[3] cos + sin))/Sqrt[2] - 
   sigc (6^(-(1/2)/n) ((rho (3 cos + Sqrt[3] sin))/sigc)^(1/n))^n /. 
  n -> 1/3` results in `(rho (Sqrt[3] cos + sin))/Sqrt[2] - (
 sigc ((rho^3 (3 cos + Sqrt[3] sin)^3)/sigc^3)^(1/3))/Sqrt[6]` which does not equal zero (By default  all the parameters are assumed complex,).

Comment: `Reduce[(rho (Sqrt[3] cos + sin))/Sqrt[2] - 
   sigc (6^(-(1/2)/n) ((rho (3 cos + Sqrt[3] sin))/sigc)^(1/n))^n == 
  0, rho, Reals]` performs "Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce."

Comment: The same issue with `Solve[(rho (Sqrt[3] cos + sin))/Sqrt[2] - 
   sigc (6^(-(1/2)/n) ((rho (3 cos + Sqrt[3] sin))/sigc)^(1/n))^n == 
  0, rho, Reals, Assumptions -> n > 0]`.

Comment: Evaluating all the parameters,e.g. `cos = 1/2; sin = Sqrt[3]/2; sigc = 50; n = 
 1/3; Reduce[(rho (Sqrt[3] cos + sin))/Sqrt[2] - 
   sigc (6^(-(1/2)/n) ((rho (3 cos + Sqrt[3] sin))/sigc)^(1/n))^n == 
  0, rho, Reals]`, I obtain `rho>0`  (or `True` for some other values of the parameters).

Comment: @Diogo: Your edit (After several comments were made.) is not described. This is not a good practice.

Comment: @user64494 For your example `eq = (rho (Sqrt[3] cos + sin))/Sqrt[2] -     sigc (6^(-(1/2)/n) ((rho (3 cos + Sqrt[3] sin))/sigc)^(1/n))^n /.    n -> 1/3` if `rho` is real and greater than zero, then `eq = 0` always.  But if `rho` is real and negative, then, yes, `eq != 0`.  If `rho` is complex, then I don't know what the solutions are.  And I'm assuming (maybe wrongly) that `rho` is not complex for this application.

Comment: @JimB: You wrote "It appears that `eq==0` for all non-zero real values of $n.$ Maybe something is wrong in the equations presented?" without any reservations in your second comment in this thread. That is all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136242/discussion-between-jimb-and-user64494).